# listar archivos / ficheros en android

Tags: java, android

Me gustaría poder abrir en un  `ListView` de una actividad los ficheros 
 que contenga mi aplicación. Estos ficheros están siendo guardados en otra actividad, y siempre con la misma extensión (`.prop` por hacerla singular).

Lo que no tengo claro como conseguir en un array la lista de estos ficheros(ya que no tengo idea de donde esta guardando cada fichero `.prop`).

Os adjunto el código cuando guardo cada fichero:

```
final EditText input = new EditText(Insercion.this);

new AlertDialog.Builder(Insercion.this)
        .setTitle("Nombre del fichero")
        .setView(input)
        .setPositiveButton("Guardar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                String editable = input.getText().toString();
                // aquí guardo lo aceptado
                try {
                FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(editable+".prop", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

                ObjectOutputStream salida=new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                salida.writeObject(carteles);
                fos.close();
                salida.close();
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("ERROR ESCRITURA");
            }
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            }
        }).show();
```

Comment: Puedes saber la ruta del fichero mediante `TuActivity.this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()`

Comment: @SergioCv como que no tienes idea donde se están guardando los ficheros, puedes verlo en la actividad que realiza esa tarea. Para mayor información agrega el código de esa actividad por favor!

Answer (score 2):

Primeramente  debes tomar en cuenta que para escribir un archivo, debes tener un lugar donde escribirlo, por lo tanto esto es incorrecto:

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(editable+".prop", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

Esto sería lo correcto si quisieras escribir un archivo en el **[almacenamiento externo](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html)**:

```
 try {
            //Escribiendo al almacenamiento externo.
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "test.prop"));
            ObjectOutputStream salida = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            salida.writeObject(carteles);
            fos.close();
            salida.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("ERROR ESCRITURA");
        }
```

No olvides agregar el permiso para realizar esta operación dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Si desearas escribir tu archivo dentro del **[almacenamiento interno](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html)**, sería de esta forma:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(getFilesDir(), "test.prop"));
```

#### Para obtener los archivos dentro un directorio es sabiendo su ubicación, la cual se obtendría de esta forma, de acuerdo a tu código:

```
  String path = getExternalFilesDir(null)+ File.separator;
```

El path sería :

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/[PAQUETE DE APLICACIÓN]/files/
```

Este sería un método para obtener los archivos dentro del directorio, y los agrega a un listView.

```
   private void listFilesProp(){
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        //obtiene ruta donde se encuentran los archivos.
        String path = getExternalFilesDir(null)+ File.separator;
        File f = new File(path);
        //obtiene nombres de archivos dentro del directorio. 
        File file[] = f.listFiles();
        for (int i=0; i < file.length; i++)
        {
            Log.d("Files", "Archivo : " + file[i].getName());
            //Agrega nombres de archivos a List para ser agregado a adapter.
            list.add(file[i].getName());
        }

        ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        //Crea Adapter
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                list );
        //Configura Adapter a ListView.
        listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias Elena, con esto esta todo mas que claro :)