# ¿Error al tratar de en listar la /sdcard?

Tags: android

Mi problema es que quiero poder listar la /sdcard obteniendo todos los archivos y ficheros mi código actual me funcionaba pero hace poco dejo de funcionar (no se porque lo ocurrió). Pero he estado investigando y he encontrado algo referente a una mal entrada a la memoria pero mi código funciona anteriormente así que no hubo de una mal entrada, hablo de anteriormente de hace como unos 3 días y hoy no funciona.

Mi código:

```
    private List<String> listaNombresArchivos;
private List<String> listaRutasArchivos;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador;
private String directorioRaiz;
private TextView carpetaActual;
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    checkExternalStoragePermission();

    Bundle ruta=getIntent().getExtras();
    String ruta1=ruta.getString("rut");
    ty=ruta.getString("mime");
    carpetaActual = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rutaActual);

    directorioRaiz =ruta1;

    verArchivosDirectorio(directorioRaiz);


}
    private void verArchivosDirectorio(String rutaDirectorio) {
    carpetaActual.setText("Estas en: " + rutaDirectorio);
    listaNombresArchivos = new ArrayList<String>();
    listaRutasArchivos = new ArrayList<String>();
    File directorioActual = new File(rutaDirectorio);
    File[] listaArchivos = directorioActual.listFiles();

    int x = 0;


    if (!rutaDirectorio.equals(directorioRaiz)) {
        listaNombresArchivos.add("../");
        listaRutasArchivos.add(directorioActual.getParent());
        x = 1;
    }

    // Almacenamos las rutas de todos los archivos y carpetas del directorio
    for (File archivo : listaArchivos) {
        listaRutasArchivos.add(archivo.getPath());
    }

    // Ordenamos la lista de archivos para que se muestren en orden alfabetico
    Collections.sort(listaRutasArchivos, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);


    // Recorredos la lista de archivos ordenada para crear la lista de los nombres
    // de los archivos que mostraremos en el listView
    for (int i = x; i < listaRutasArchivos.size(); i++){
        File archivo = new File(listaRutasArchivos.get(i));
        if (archivo.isFile()) {
            listaNombresArchivos.add(archivo.getName());
        } else {
            listaNombresArchivos.add("/" + archivo.getName());
        }
    }

    // Si no hay ningun archivo en el directorio lo indicamos 
    if (listaArchivos.length < 1) {
        listaNombresArchivos.add("No hay ningun archivo");
        listaRutasArchivos.add(rutaDirectorio);
    }


    // Creamos el adaptador y le asignamos la lista de los nombres de los
    // archivos y el layout para los elementos de la lista
    adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.text_view_lista_archivos, listaNombresArchivos);
    setListAdapter(adaptador);
}

    private void checkExternalStoragePermission() {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para leer.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso para leer!");
    }
}
```

Este código se encarga de en listar un directorio, para mas informacion visite su pagina de origen: http://programandoointentandolo.com/2014/06/como-hacer-un-explorador-de-archivos-en-android.html

Mi LogCat:

```
04-20 20:09:33.943: I/dalvikvm(16382):   #22  pc 00000dce  
/system/bin/app_process
04-20 20:09:33.943: I/dalvikvm(16382):   #23  pc 00016f4c  
/system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+35)
04-20 20:09:33.943: I/dalvikvm(16382):   at java.io.File.listImpl(Native 
Method)
04-20 20:09:33.943: I/dalvikvm(16382):   at java.io.File.list(File.java:749)
04-20 20:09:33.943: I/dalvikvm(16382):   at 
java.io.File.listFiles(File.java:791)
04-20 20:09:33.953: I/dalvikvm(16382):   at 
com.example.virtualdiskmediaplayer.Main.verArchivosDirectorio(Main.java:82)
04-20 20:09:33.953: I/dalvikvm(16382):   at 
com.example.virtualdiskmediaplayer.Main.onCreate(Main.java:66)
04-20 20:09:33.953: I/dalvikvm(16382):   at 
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5188)
04-20 20:09:33.953: I/dalvikvm(16382):   at 
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
04-20 20:09:33.953: I/dalvikvm(16382):   at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2085)
04-20 20:09:33.953: I/dalvikvm(16382):   at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2146)
04-20 20:09:33.953: I/dalvikvm(16382):   at 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
04-20 20:09:33.953: I/dalvikvm(16382):   at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
04-20 20:09:33.953: I/dalvikvm(16382):   at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-20 20:09:33.953: I/dalvikvm(16382):   at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-20 20:09:33.953: I/dalvikvm(16382):   at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
04-20 20:09:33.953: I/dalvikvm(16382):   at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-20 20:09:33.953: I/dalvikvm(16382):   at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-20 20:09:33.953: I/dalvikvm(16382):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
04-20 20:09:33.953: I/dalvikvm(16382):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
04-20 20:09:33.953: I/dalvikvm(16382):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-20 20:09:33.953: E/dalvikvm(16382): VM aborting
04-20 20:09:33.953: A/libc(16382): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d 
(code=1), thread 16382 (diskmediaplayer)
```

Si conocen o notan algo. Estaré encantado de escuchar sus preguntas y comentarios. Gracias.

Comment: Existe una pregunta similar : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7826/listar-ficheros-en-android

Comment: Tienes razón son parecidas, pero la mía trata de un error y la otra de como hacerlo, yo ya se hacerlo, solo que ha aparecido un error, ademas este contenido es diferente al otro, pero gracias por mostrarme la otra pregunta me ha dado algo de que pensar. Gracias.

Comment: Ok en tu LogCat trata de buscar donde diga "Caused by"  y agregalo, ya que lo que agregaste no indica cual es el problema.

Comment: Amiga gracias por su ayuda, el error no se encontraba en mi aplicación si no en el emulador. Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Que bien que lo solucionaste , saludos! @AbrahamP

Comment: Igualmente, me da gusto tu interés. Gracias